# Calling Xalan function

Tags: xslt, xalan

In my stylesheet that I try to debug in XMLspy, I have the following line:

```
xsl:for-each select="xalan:nodeset($Order)//Lines"
```

When I try to parse it in XMLSpy, I get the error: 'function 'xalan:nodeset' was not defined. I use the external XSL transform, but I think it`s not enough and I have to define it within my stylesheet.

I`d appreciate help on how to call this function locally on my laptop from the stylesheet.

Comment: You would need to configure XMLSpy to use Xalan and not its built-in XSLT processor if you want to use Xalan specific extension function. On the other hand a nodeset function is not necessary in XSLT 2.0 and later at all which XMLSpy supports so you could simply replace `xalan:nodeset($Order)//Lines` with `$Order//Lines` if you use XSLT 2.0 in XMLSpy.

Comment: You don't need to, and cannot, define the Xalan nodeset function in your own stylesheet.  If you are using Xalan and have correctly bound the prefix 'xalan' to the right namespace, that should be enough to make it work.  (This is of course separate from the fact that no one here can believe you need this function, since it's unnecessary in XSLT 2.0.  If you really do have reasons for needing to use 1.0, you will have to say explicitly that you need to use 1.0 -- even then, I predict no one will believe you.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen  Lots of people have to use XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I believe you, but I still predict that not everyone will.  And I am interested in knowing what situations require the use of 1.0.  Stylesheets to run natively in Web browsers; environments where Java is unavailable.  What other reasons arise, I wonder?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Consider for example applications with a built-in XSLT 1.0 engine - such as some databases or Adobe InDesign.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using the Xalan processor (and even if you are), replace `xalan:nodeset()` with the more generic [`exsl:node-set()`](http://exslt.org/exsl/index.html) - where `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`.

This is assuming you're using XSLT 1.0. As mentioned in the comments, no `node-set()` function is required in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Actually for xalan I was using external xsl program in Spy: java.exe -cp "d:\xalan\2.7.2\xalan.jar" org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in %1 -xsl %3 -out %2. Still after replacing xalan function to exsl:node-set I get the same error. Besides namespace shall I predefine it within xsl file or in xmlspy itself?

Comment: Does XMLSpy use Xalan when you "debug" XSLT?

Comment: @dcx You need to bind the prefix you are using (be it `xalan:` or `exsl:`) to a namespace. This declaration needs to be in the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: @Michael could you please describe in few words how to define it? I`ve added xmlns:exsl but what else there, should I do so debugger could call this function? It works fine in my webserver when I promote xsl file and use it for email content, but I just can`t get it working in xmlspy.

Comment: @Michael I applied the same but I still get this. I begin to wonder if there is something off with my XMLspy or Java. I`ll try to check this on other PCs.

Comment: @dcx If you're not getting the same result as shown in my links, then the problem is with the transformation itself - not with the XSLT code.